# PHP adding to array after JSON encoding

Tags: php

I'm  encoding a very basic array like this.

```
$c['A']=NULL;

$c=json_encode($c);
```

I later want to decode the json and add a new key

```
$c=json_decode($c);

$c[B]=NULL;
```

The problem is that $c is now an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_decode()` is returning PHP Object. You need 2nd parameter if you want it to be array:

```
$c=json_decode($c, true);
```

look:http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$c` as an object:

```
$c->B = NULL;
```